# How to export a shape to KML preserving the symbology?

Tags: qgis, kml

I want to export a shapefile layer to KML preserving the symbology, I do it with the export option and select the KML file type but it does not save the symbology when opening it in Google Earth.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta a inglés, son las normas del sitio.

Comment: Please translate your question into English because this is an English-only site.